# How to focus the autofocus element in jQuery ui dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog, autofocus

As I want to set an element as focused when a jQuery dialog is open.
I wrote kind of this code:

```
$(".selector").dialog({
    title: "dialog",
    buttons: [
        { text: "Yes", click: function () { } },
        { text: "No", autofocus: true }
    ]
});
```

This is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WuJuntao/jdaefLuz/) for this case.

This seems work as I want in IE9+/Firefox/etc, but not in IE8.
So I found the _focusTabbable function in jquery-ui.

```
var hasFocus = this.element.find("[autofocus]");
if ( !hasFocus.length ) {
    hasFocus = this.element.find(":tabbable");
}
if (!hasFocus.length) {
    hasFocus = this.uiDialogButtonPane.find(":tabbable");
}
```

This will only find the autofocus element in the ui-content, not in the button panel.
How come there would be a call to find :tabbable in uiDialogButtonPane, but not applied [autofocus]?

More interesting, even in IE11/Firefox I saw that the function focused the "Yes" button in the end, but happened to popup a dialog with focus at "No" button. Cannot find a reason.

Comment: Please provide fiddle

Comment: This is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WuJuntao/jdaefLuz/) for this case. But the jquery-ui version is incorrect and I cannot choose the correct version to make it even work.